# react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera-roll

after running commands
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease

it gives error

Task :@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\aksha\Desktop\Akshay\node_modules@react-native-camera-roll\camera-roll\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\cameraroll\CameraRollPackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Task :react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' (type 'LibraryJniLibsTask').

Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\aksha\Desktop\Akshay\node_modules@react-native-camera-roll\camera-roll\android\build\intermediates\stripped_native_libs\release\out'.

Reason: Task ':react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' uses this output of task ':@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

Possible solutions:

Declare task ':@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' as an input of ':react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars'.
Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' from ':react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' using Task#dependsOn.
Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' from ':react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' using Task#mustRunAfter.
For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 29s

how to solve this problem

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).